# Como fazer INNER JOIN entre duas tabelas?

Tags: mysql

Preciso juntar os campos da tabela "funcionarios" e "clientes".O problema é que os dados se repetem,dessa forma:
[image: "]

Acredito que tenha algo a ver com chave estrangeira e chave primária.
O primeiro campo "nome" pertece à tabela "funcionarios", o outro pertence à "clientes".

```html
create database meuBanco;

 use meuBanco;
 create table Produtos(
 codigo int(10), 
 nome varchar(20), 
 valor float, 
 quantidade_em_estoque int(10), 
 ativo enum('S','N'),
primary key(nome)
 );


  create table Clientes(
 codigo int(10), 
 nome varchar(20),
 endereco varchar(50),
primary key(nome)
 );
 
 
  create table Funcionarios(
 codigo int(10), 
 nome varchar(20),
 cargo varchar(20), 
 ativo enum('S','N'),
 primary key(nome)
 );
 
 create table vendas(
  codigo_venda int(10), 
  codigo_cliente int(10),
  codigo_vendedor int(10), 
  data_completa_de_venda date
 
 );
 create table detalhe_da_venda( 
 codigo_venda int(10), 
 codigo_produto int(10),
 quantidade_de_produto_vendido int(10)
 
 );

insert into Produtos value
(1,'JANELA','134.56','10','S'),
(2,'FOGAO','334.56','20','N'),
(3,'COMPUTADOR','15.6','30','S'),
(4,'CELULAR','114.76','40','N'),
(5,'CADEIRA','184.96','50','S');


insert into Clientes value
(6,'ALBERTO','Av. Presidente Wilson - 412'),
(7,'BRUNO','Av. Bartolomeu De Gusmão - 211'),
(8,'CARLOS','Av. Ana Costa - 416'),
(9,'DANILO','Av. Padre Anchiete - 718'),
(10,'ESTER','Av. Marechal Deodoro - 702');

insert into Funcionarios value
(11,'ALESSANDRA','VENDEDOR','S'),
(12,'BRENO','GERENTE','N'),
(13,'CARLOS','ENTREGADOR','S'),
(14,'DANIEL','MARCENEIRO','N'),
(15,'ELENA','VENDEDORA','S');

insert into Vendas value
(16,001,111,'2019-05-01'),
(17,002,222,'2015-04-10'),
(18,003,333,'2018-07-09'),
(19,004,444,'2013-04-03'),
(20,005,555,'2019-10-12'),
(21,006,666,'2019-10-02'),
(22,007,777,'2019-10-31'),
(23,008,888,'2019-05-12'),
(24,009,999,'2019-10-29'),
(25,0010,101010,'2019-06-12');


insert into detalhe_da_venda value
(26,00070,5),
(27,00080,23),
(28,00090,2),
(29,000010,1),
(30,000011,3),
(31,000034,34),
(32,000043,22),
(33,00044,11),
(34,000022,45),
(35,000000,4);

select*from detalhe_da_venda;


select * from vendas;





alter table vendas
add column qt_produtos_vendidos int(10);




select 
funcionarios.nome,
clientes.nome
from funcionarios join clientes;
```

Comment: Para fazer uma INNER JOIN você precisa especificar os campos de cada uma das tabelas que terão valores iguais. Em suas tabelas não consegui identificar tais campos. Se não existir um valor comum a ambas tabelas o que você terá, como aconteceu em seu exemplo, um produto cartesiano.

Comment: O problema não está em Primary Key ou Foreign Key. Está duplicando porque para cada registro da tabela base da query, está retornando uma das linhas da tabela utilizada no join. Procure rever seu conceito de join e qual a lógica de relacionar cliente e funcionário?

Comment: O que vou dizer agora não tem a ver com o problema do join, mas com definição das primary keys das suas tabelas. Suas tabelas têm o campo `codigo`, que é o campo suposto para ser a primary key. Para garantir que o nome não repita, você pode criar índice único para o campo nome.

Comment: Qual é a pergunta que você precisa responder? Assim fica mais fácil para te orientar.

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi certo, você quer juntar as tabelas que possuem o mesmo nome, correto?

Você pode tentar algo como:

```
SELECT nome_coluna FROM Clientes INNER JOIN Funcionarios ON Clientes.nome = Funcionarios.nome;
```

Não é muito recomendável utilizar o nome para isso. O melhor seria um valor único (talvez codigo).

Answer (score -2):

Como o camarada falou acima, não é mt utilizado o join p/ fazer junção de tabelas onde vc quer buscar a junção de caracteres que sejam iguais. Coloquei um código abaixo p vc fazer a junção da tabela cliente com a de venda, onde vc busca o código.

```
SELECT 
a.codigo,
a.nome,
b.nome
FROM cliente a 
INNER JOIN venda b
ON a.codigo=b.codigo
ORDER BY 1;
```